# Any Google API to get Best route among locations having latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For example I have 5 location with lat and lng. My requirement is I need to get the best route among these location along with current location

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=lat,lng&destination=lat,lng&mode=driving&sensor=false&alternatives=true&waypoints=[]

The above API may get source to destination best route but not the best way among the 5 locations

For example
Currently I am at Washington, I have to visit New York, Chicago, Massachusetts, Portland and Boston. In which order I can visit these places, so that travelling distance should me minimal.

Comment: I guess to achieve this we need to have our own logic by using the above API request

Answer (score 0):

To get the best route you need to add `optimize:true` in the `waypoints`.

Here is an example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: even if I dint give the destination I need to get the route from source to last point of the waypoint. Simply say I need save my time to travel. For that the above URL is not work, destination should be compulsory.